# amfphp multidimensional array

Tags: arrays, amfphp

in my Flex App, I have a 2-dimensional Array, something like this:

```
arr[0][0] = "11";
arr[0][1] = "12";

arr[1][0] = "21";
arr[1][1] = "22";
```

I'm sending this array to my webservice:

```
amfWebService.doSomethingWithThatArray(arr);
```

I'm checking the result of the function (which is as string) with an Alert.

Now to my problem: PHP somehow does not recognize the array properly.

To see whats arriving at PHP I've implemented this:

```
if(is_array($arr))
    if(is_array($arr[0]))
        if(is_array($arr[0][0]))
            return "this can't be true";
        else
            return "no 3 dimensions";
    else
        return "no 2 dimensions";
else
    return "no array";
```

Now guess what! My Alert shows me "this can't be true", which means that arr[0][0] is recognized as an array and not as "11", which it should.

Anyone has an idea what this is about? Its AMFPHP 1.9 and Flex 3

Comment: Forget it.. The problem was based somewhere else.. I got the values for my array from a dictionary, and although they were strings you seem to have to convert them with ".toString()" again when sending them to amfphp. Otherwise they will not be recognized as strings.

Answer (score 1):

You could have used `print_r()` to display the structure or `$arr`. Most convenient way to find such problems - after using a proper debugger.